# Correlation between a stock and the index without the stock

Tags: correlation, index

The weight of stock i in index m is w.
The returns are, respectively, r(i) and r(m).

I know the volatility s(i) of i, the volatility s(m) of m and the correlation rho(i, m) between i and m.

The index x is m without i:

r(x) = (r(m) - w*r(i)) / (1 - w)

s(x) = sqrt[(w/(1-w)*s(i))^2 + (1/(1-w)*s(m))^2 - 2*rho(i, m)*s(i)*s(m)*(w/(1-w))*(1/(1-w))]

**Can I get the correlation rho(i, x) between i and x?**

(I am sorry for not using LaTeX)

--- edit ---

I may have found it.

The relevant properties should be:

1. COV(cX, Y) = cCOV(X, Y)
2. COV(X + Y, Z) = COV(X, Z) + COV(Y, Z)

In my problem:

COV(i, x) = COV(i, (1/(1-w))*m - (w/(1-w))*i) = (1/(1-w))*COV(i, m) - (w/(1-w))*VAR(i)

and I have all the inputs needed.

Comment: The general idea looks correct. You write down variances, covariances and correlations explicitly and see if you can solve for the unknown using what is known.